# How to import metat utf-8 implicitly in index.html?

Tags: angular

i was asked to import metat utf-8 implicitly

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>

    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <title>Projet</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png">
    <link type="text/html" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"/> 
</head>
<body ><app-root></app-root>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create A service in a   import Meta from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SEOService { 


constructor(private meta: Meta) {
   meta.addTags([
      {name: 'description', content: 'Title and Meta tags examples'},   
      {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},   
      {name: 'robots', content: 'INDEX, FOLLOW'},
      {name: 'author', content: 'ABCD'},
      {name: 'keywords', content: 'TypeScript, Angular'},
      {name: 'date', content: '2018-06-02', scheme: 'YYYY-MM-DD'},
      {httpEquiv: 'Content-Type', content: 'text/html'},
      {property: 'og:title', content: "My Text"},
      {property: 'og:type', content: "website"},
      {charset: 'UTF-8'}
   ]);       
   }
   }
```

You can also take a reference from [Angular meta service](https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-meta-service-for-meta-tags)